# Unable to install gem ruby-debug19 on win7 with installed ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-debug, ruby-1.9.3

I've tried many solutions but nothing seems to work!
I use Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.1.3 and I want to install the ruby-debug19 gem. This ist what I get from the PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\**\**\**> gem install ruby-debug19
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug19:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:39: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... yes
checking for insns.inc... yes
checking for insns_info.inc... yes
checking for eval_intern.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
generating ruby_debug-i386-mingw32.def
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling ruby_debug.c
ruby_debug.c:29:19: error: conflicting types for 'rb_iseq_compile_with_option'
C:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p0/vm_core.h:505:7: note: previous declaration of 'rb_iseq_compile_with_option' was here
ruby_debug.c: In function 'context_jump':
ruby_debug.c:2414:53: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
ruby_debug.c:2428:27: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
make: *** [ruby_debug.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've had a similar issue getting ruby-debug-base19x installed and I've been able to get it successfully installed using the following:

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19x -v 0.11.30.pre3
```

This worked on my development machine which is running window 7 along with pik (see https://github.com/vertiginous/pik), devkit (see https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit) and Ruby 1.9.3p0 / 1.9.2p290

Here's a sample of what you should see when installing it:

```
C:\>gem install ruby-debug-base19x -v 0.11.30.pre3
Fetching: columnize-0.3.6.gem (100%)
Fetching: archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: ruby_core_source-0.1.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: linecache19-0.5.12.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed columnize-0.3.6
Successfully installed archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2
Successfully installed ruby_core_source-0.1.5
Successfully installed linecache19-0.5.12
Successfully installed ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre3
5 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for columnize-0.3.6...
Installing ri documentation for archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2...
Installing ri documentation for ruby_core_source-0.1.5...
Installing ri documentation for linecache19-0.5.12...
Installing ri documentation for ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre3...
Installing RDoc documentation for columnize-0.3.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby_core_source-0.1.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for linecache19-0.5.12...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre3...
```

While this worked for me it is a moving target in that we're using a pre release version of the gem to get things done. Best to keep a eye out for a release.

Just an additional note that at the time of writing the current pre release was 0.11.30.pre6 which doesn't work so just doing the following will fail:

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19x --pre
```

Comment: what is this mystery gem ruby-debug-base19x dare I ask?

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you have to change the line in Gemfile: gem "ruby-debug-base19x", "~> 0.11.29"

Answer (score 2):

Similar question was asked on jetbrains site, and its solution worked for me:
http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5443846#5443846

You should install new linecache19 gem via

```
curl -OL http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem
```

And then ruby-debug-base19x via

```
gem install --pre ruby-debug-base19x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I've installed this gem. But nevertheless rubymine wants the ruby-debug-ide for debug-mode. If I try to install this gem I get the following error in the PowerShell: ERROR: Error installing ruby-debug-ide: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need to have [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) installed

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem with Mac OS X rvm ruby 1.9.3-p0 and a `gem install ruby-debug-base19x --pre` did the trick.

This installs the pre10 release which seems to do the trick.